# Nasm — как правильно указать длину строки?

Tags: ассемблер

По задумке код должен сравнивать *a* и *b*. Но выводит сразу 3 ответа. *Debug* показывает верный прыжок в верный блок, но когда дело доходит до прерывания, он выводит сразу 3 ответа (*wat*):

```
A is bigger
B is bigger
A == B
```

Вот код (*nasm*):

```
BITS 64

section .data
    a dd 45
    b dd 6
    msg1 db 'A is bigger', 0xa
    msg2 db 'B is bigger', 0xa
    msg3 db 'A == B', 0xa
    msg1l equ $-msg1
    msg2l equ $-msg2
    msg3l equ $-msg3


section .text
    global _start

_start:          
        mov eax, [a]
        mov ebx, [b]

        cmp eax, ebx
        ja bigger
        cmp eax, ebx
        jb less

        mov eax, 4            ; equal
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg3
        mov edx, msg3l
        int 0x80
        jmp endif

bigger:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg1
        mov edx, msg1l
        int 0x80
        jmp endif
less:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg2
        mov edx, msg2l 
        int 0x80
        jmp endif
endif:        
        mov eax, 1
        int 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

длина строк вычисляется неправильно: в `msg1l` у вас попадает длина всех трёх в сумме, а в `msg2l` — длина второй и третьей.

надо так:

```
...
msg1 db 'A is bigger', 0xa
msg1l equ $-msg1
msg2 db 'B is bigger', 0xa
msg2l equ $-msg2
msg3 db 'A == B', 0xa
msg3l equ $-msg3
...
```